# Configure Kamon and AspectjWeaver in Play application

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, aspectj, sbt-aspectj

I'm trying to configure a play application to use Kamon. I've created a new play application using

```
activator new kamon-play play-scala
```

Then I [posted it on github](https://github.com/developmentalmadness/kamon-play). I'm running on OS X 10.11.1 and I'm running JDK 1.8.0_65-b17 and the project is configured with scala 2.11.6. I've configured it (to the best of my understanding) based on the [instructions for configuring Play](http://kamon.io/integrations/web-and-http-toolkits/play/) as well as the sbt-aspectj-runner [kamon-play example](https://github.com/kamon-io/sbt-aspectj-runner/tree/master/examples/kamon-play). However when I try to run the application using either:

```
sbt run
```

or

```
activator run
```

I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [11/25/2015 09:04:39.574] [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-9] [ModuleLoader(akka://kamon)] 

  ___                           _      ___   _    _                                 ___  ___ _            _
 / _ \                         | |    |_  | | |  | |                                |  \/  |(_)          (_)
/ /_\ \ ___  _ __    ___   ___ | |_     | | | |  | |  ___   __ _ __   __ ___  _ __  | .  . | _  ___  ___  _  _ __    __ _
|  _  |/ __|| '_ \  / _ \ / __|| __|    | | | |/\| | / _ \ / _` |\ \ / // _ \| '__| | |\/| || |/ __|/ __|| || '_ \  / _` |
| | | |\__ \| |_) ||  __/| (__ | |_ /\__/ / \  /\  /|  __/| (_| | \ V /|  __/| |    | |  | || |\__ \\__ \| || | | || (_| |
\_| |_/|___/| .__/  \___| \___| \__|\____/   \/  \/  \___| \__,_|  \_/  \___||_|    \_|  |_/|_||___/|___/|_||_| |_| \__, |
            | |                                                                                                      __/ |
            |_|                                                                                                     |___/

 It seems like your application was not started with the -javaagent:/path-to-aspectj-weaver.jar option but Kamon detected
 the following modules which require AspectJ to work properly:

      kamon-akka, kamon-scala, kamon-play

 If you need help on setting up the aspectj weaver go to http://kamon.io/introduction/get-started/ for more info. On the
 other hand, if you are sure that you do not need or do not want to use the weaver then you can disable this error message
 by changing the kamon.show-aspectj-missing-warning setting in your configuration file.
```

I've tried all of the following:

- Adding `aspectj-play-runner:run` to the plugins.sbt file (doesn't compile)
- passing in the javaagent argument to activator:

  `activator -J-javaagent::~/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar`

but that results in the following error:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : :~/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

- passing in the javaagent argument to sbt:

  `sbt run -Djavaagent:~/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar`

also tried

```
sbt run -Djavaagent:~/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar -Daspectj-play-runner:run
```

UPDATE

I figured out that aspectj-play-runner:run is an sbt task/command so I tried that:

```
sbt
aspectj-runner:run
```

which outputs:

```
[WeavingURLClassLoader] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
java.lang.RuntimeException: Kamon has not been started yet. You must either explicitlt call Kamon.start(...) or enable automatic startup by adding -Dkamon.auto-start=true to your JVM options.
```

So then I tried:

```
sbt -Dkamon.auto-start=true
aspectj-runner:run
```

Which outputs:

```
[WeavingURLClassLoader] warning javax.* types are not being woven because the weaver option '-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true' has not been specified
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$IO: application.conf: java.io.IOException: resource not found on classpath: application.conf
```

Lastly, the documents actually say I should be running

```
sbt
aspectj-play-runner:run
```

But the command/task isn't even recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to contact @kamonteam on twitter and this was their reply:

> @dvMENTALmadness currently we have a bug in kamon when using the akka and play modules together, until next release that we hope do in...... the weekend for now the only option is remove the kamon-akka module :(

Based on that I removed references to the kamon-akka module from my build.sbt and application.config and now it's working. Once I have an issue # from the project I'll track it and post when the issue is resolved. In the meantime, [here's the commit](https://github.com/developmentalmadness/kamon-play/commit/190b0beb785abffbf7aafaaa2f09339ca84ac329) that "fixed" the issue for me. I still need the akka module for it to be a complete solution for me however.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to set JAVA_OPTS environment variable.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-javaagent:$HOME/.ivy2/cache/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/jars/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar"
sbt run
```